# Drop a table at a time of uninstall extension in magento

Tags: php, magento

In magento when i install my own created extension that create one table into database. but when i uninstall extension. It just remove the extension file and folder from magento.
**I would also like to drop the table that i was created at the time of extension active.**

Please help me I am new magento developer.

Comment: Good Questions  of this type of code

Comment: Hello drop extension table from your database. Please backup of your DB before drop command

Answer (score 0):

When removing files of an extension, the data stored in the database (dedicated tables and config in core_config_data) are not deleted.

To do this, you either create a sql upgrade setup to delete those entries, and upgrade your extension, or manually do it in phpmyadmin.

You can just run queries likes

```
DROP TABLE 'mytable'; DELETE FROM 'core_config_data' WHERE path LIKE '%mymodule%';
```

Of course the cleanest way would be the other, create these request in a sql file upgrade from your version to the next and run it by upgrading the version in the etc/config.xml on the extension.

There isn't a tool that will "remove all unused extension tables" automatically, as that could potentially be quite dangerous (removing still used, or tables where the extension is just disabled, etc).

If you want to proceed you can do it from PHP MyAdmin and delete the unused table but before that Backup is highly recommended !!